# How can we use same domain for laravel (https//:example.com) and nodejs (https//:example.com:8443) on AWS EC2?

Tags: node.js, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I have created a Laravel application and used node js with socket.io for the chat and I want both the application to run on the same domain and my website is hosted on the AWS server. I had installed an SSL certificate using ACM

When I open my Laravel website (https//:example.com) on a browser it is working fine but when I tried to open the Nodejs application with port (https//:example.com:8443) browser said 'This site can’t be reached' and I am getting this error 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'.

I have already added port 8443 in inbound rules
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE7ha.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check whether you have allowed the 8443 port in the ufw.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not using ufw and it is not enabled on my server

Comment: @james: Can you enable the ufw for the port 8443 and check it once.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it didn't work. it is working when I tried with IP address but not with domain name